# Am I right about measuring current, and power

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, ac, measurement

I have a meter that can measure: current, active power, reactive power and complex power.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7kkNS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So, when I measure the four things: current, active power, reactive power and complex power. Will they be described by the following formula's?:

1. Current:
   $$I=\frac{\hat{V}}{\sqrt{2}\cdot\left|Z_{in}\right|}$$
2. Real power:
   $$P=UI\cos\varphi=\frac{\hat{V}}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{\hat{V}}{\sqrt{2}\cdot\left|Z_{in}\right|}\cdot\cos\varphi=\frac{\hat{V}^2}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\left|Z_{in}\right|}\cdot\cos\varphi$$
3. Reactive power:
   $$Q=UI\sin\varphi=\frac{\hat{V}}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{\hat{V}}{\sqrt{2}\cdot\left|Z_{in}\right|}\cdot\sin\varphi=\frac{\hat{V}^2}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\left|Z_{in}\right|}\cdot\sin\varphi$$
4. Complex power:
   $$S=UI=\sqrt{P^2+Q^2}$$
5. Power factor:
   $$\varphi=\left|\arg\left(V\right)-\arg\left(I\right)\right|=\left|\arg\left(V\right)-\arg\left(\frac{V}{\text{Z}_{in}}\right)\right|=$$
   $$\left|\arg\left(V\right)-\left(\arg\left(V\right)-\arg\left(\text{Z}_{in}\right)\right)\right|=\left|\arg\left(Z_{in}\right)\right|$$

Comment: What does the user manual say? (Add a link to the product datasheet or user manual in your question.) As drawn in your schematic you have no neutral reference so you can only measure current. The neutral reference is required to measure voltage.

Comment: Apparently 4 is mislabeled  ( Apparent Power)

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I edited my question.

Comment: All your calculations seem to assume sinusoidal voltage and current waveforms. Most good modern meters will handle waveforms with high harmonic content. To do this they need to sample voltage and current many times per mains cycle and compute the real and reactive power by averaging the instantaneous values.

Comment: @Transistor Yes, they are sinusoidal voltage and current waveforms.

Comment: @asd34w. The shape of your waveforms will not determine how the meter was designed. You haven't provided any info on the test equipment so nobody can help you. All the info in the question, please.

Comment: @Transistor I do not know that kind of equipment. Just a meter that can measure the things I need

Comment: Your post starts with "*I have a meter that can measure: current, active power, reactive power and complex power.*" How can you not know the make and model?

Comment: @asd34w   Your questions opens with "I have a meter" but in truth all you have are equations. Did you only want feedback on that?  If so Complex Power would be in the vector form P+jQ and S is a scalar called Apparent Power or VI. or (U*I) in the eu.